# Как получить background-position-x и -y через jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть `div` с `background-position: 150px 50px`.
Получить значение свойства можно так

```
$(this).css("background-position");
```

Как получить по отдельности `background-position-x` и `-y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть свойство background-position-x, попробуйте через него.
Как вариант можно javascript'ом разбивать 150px 50px.

```
var str = "150px 50px";
var arr = str.split(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: В том и проблема, что background-position-x не работает. Попробую ваш вариант. Спасибо.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, `background-position-x` поддерживается не всеми браузерами.